# PIG - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 5, column 0. Encountered: <EOF> after : ""

Tags: apache-pig

Input data:

> 14.323.74.653 - - [26/Oct/2011:21:07:00 -0500] "GET /demo HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0-rc4"

My Code:

```
REGISTER /home/training/pig/JAR/piggybank.jar;   
A = LOAD 'weblogsmall.txt' USING TextLoader() as (line:chararray);  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL($0,'^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)));  
STORE B INTO 'weblogsmallout';
```

Would you please shed some light, where exactly I am going wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you probably missing quote at end:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL($0,'^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)'));
```

Comment: Thank you. Program went to success, but the map file (part-m-00000) generated with no data. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Shitansu.

Comment: Try use [dump](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/test.html#dump) to check results. Read [tutorial](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/tutorial.html), Try separate commands to check results, for example `C=REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL($0,'^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)')`